# angularJS I want to add load Event at .bind function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
elem.bind('keydown keyup keypress', function(event) {}
```

I use keydown, keyup, keypress event.
and want to add load event.
how do I add load event?

Comment: what is the purpose of using of load event ?

Answer (score 1):

```
angular("mymodule").directive( 'onReady', function( $parse ) {
   return {
       restrict: 'AE',
       link: function( $scope, elem, attrs ) {    
          elem.ready(function(){
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                var func = $parse(attrs.onReady);
                func($scope);
            })
          })
       }
    }
})
```

use it like

```
<div on-ready="mymethod()"></div>
```

where mymethod is ur function in controller